# Varying alpha or colors for pyplot markers based on data

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have a fairly large data set containing positions of "star particles" that I've plotted using matplotlib. The data is organized into columns, three of which correspond to the x, y, and z coordinates. I plotted the x and y coordinates, but I want to be able to use the z coordinates as a kind of colormap for the particles. For example, particles with larger z coordinates have lower alpha or are colored differently. Currently my code looks like this:

```
f = open(input_file)
line = f.readline()
line = f.readline()
px=[]
py=[]
pz=[]
for line in f:
    ldata = line.split()
    x = np.float(ldata[2])
    y = np.float(ldata[3])
    z = np.float(ldata[4])
px.append(x)
py.append(y)
pz.append(z)
plt.plot(px,py,'ro',alpha=0.1)
plt.savefig(output_file)
```

I'm new to python

Comment: See the answers to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139621/python-matplotlib-scatter-plot-changing-colour-of-data-points-based-on-given-c?rq=1

you want to pass colors as RGBA, where A defines the alpha value.

Comment: often the matplotlib gallery is helpful (loads a whole lot of little pictures): http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list of colors using `plt.cm.` and change the alpha values (last column of RGBA array) to match your `pz` data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

px = np.arange(0,10,0.5)
py = np.random.randn(20)
pz = np.arange(0,1,0.05) 
colors = plt.cm.Reds(np.arange(0,1,0.05))
colors[:,-1] = pz 

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(px,py,color=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Keep in mind that the alpha keyword for [scatter/plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) only accepts values between 0 and 1. If your `pz` data is not in that range, you will need to scale it or modify it in order for this to work.

EDIT: Edited thanks to comment from @cphlewis and this should be much more efficient than my original answer

Comment: @cphlewis Thanks! Made the changes to my answer

Comment: Thanks a ton. One follow up question: when I do this and use
    plt.colorbar().set_label('text',rotation=90)
I get an error that says "TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable
", and a blank colorbar that looks as though it has two dimensions. How do I fix this?
To be clear, I'm mapping both the RGB values and the alpha values to (different) variables but I really only care about the RGB values being shown on the colorbar. Thanks.