Pandas bar plot with multiple alpha values
I am trying to create a bar plot with alpha transparency values for different time series.
I thought the code below would give me that, as I've seen elsewhere lists can be passed via the alpha kwarg, but I get an error (included below). What am I missing?
Code:
plt.figure()
df.plot(kind="bar", alpha=[.5,1])

Error message:
TypeError: alpha must be numeric or None, not <class 'list'>


Read the error message. parameter alpha of the pandas plot function must be passed numeric or None, and cannot be passed list.

This may be of help : Varying alpha or colors for pyplot markers based on data  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846927/varying-alpha-or-colors-for-pyplot-markers-based-on-data

Basically, you just need to set the alpha value for each bar using a for loop. Here, I provide a working example on how to achieve that with the set_alpha method, providing a list with the desired alpha values:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_series = ['2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04']
values = [10, 15, 7, 10]
alpha_values = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.bar(time_series, values)

for bar, alpha in zip(bars, alpha_values):
    bar.set_alpha(alpha)

ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Values')
plt.show()

The result of this code will be as follows:


Thanks much...using your solution was able to modify to return what I was looking for below.

Thanks to @Kelo's input, was able to get what I'm looking for via the below:
ax = df.plot(kind="bar", color=colors)
for bar in ax.containers[0]:
    bar.set_alpha(.5)


Versus original:

